# audio and video not correctly sync after concatenation

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video, mp4, video-encoding

totally new to video editing in general and in need of some help =)

command that I'm using (windows batch):

```
(echo file cucca.jpg.mp4 & echo file cucca.fade.mp4 & echo file cucca.jpg.mp4)>cucca.txt & ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i cucca.txt -y cucca.intro.mp4
```

expected result:

- audio and video should be in sync
- the resulting video should be: first video then second video then first video displayed again
- the video should last 6m13s (6s + 6m01s + 6s)

actual result:

- cucca.intro.mp4 starts correctly, both audio and video are in sync, after the first video ends (6 seconds) audio is not in synch with video anymore
- the first video is shown correctly, then the second video starts but the first video is not repeated at the end
- the video lasts around 6m39s

I would guess that somehow the audio/video streams should have the same format, but I do know how to generate a video with the exact formats needed.

would anyone please have any tips on how to fix this?

### detailed info:

- cucca.jpg.mp4: it's a video that is generated from an image plus an audio file, both audio and video fade in and out

  - `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i cucca.jpg -i music.ogg -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=3,fade=t=out:st=3:d=3,format=yuv420p [v]; [1:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=3,afade=t=out:st=3:d=3 [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -t 6 cucca.jpg.mp4 -y`

ffprobe cucca.jpg.mp4

```
ffprobe version 2021-10-28-git-e84c83ef98-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavformat    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 15.100 /  8. 15.100
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cucca.jpg.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.8.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 376 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 237 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

ffprobe cucca.fade.mp4

```
ffprobe version 2021-10-28-git-e84c83ef98-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavformat    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 15.100 /  8. 15.100
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cucca.fade.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.8.100
  Duration: 00:06:01.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3159 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3022 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: Looking at ffprobe's output for both video streams, one says yuvj420p and one says yuv420p ... Not sure you can concat those without reencoding and the appropriate -filter_complex and -map options.

Comment: Also the audio sample rates differ (44100 vs 48000). What is the command to make `cucca.fade.mp4`? Depending on that command it may be possible to do everything (generate segments and concatenate) in 1 command.